# using circular memory to make the 1 second sound delay in verilog

Tags: memory, verilog, delay

```
module delay(
input [11:0] data_in,
input delay_clk,    //here i will use a 20kHz clk
output reg [11:0] data_out
    );

    reg[11:0]memory[0:20000];
    reg[15:0]write_index;//i
    reg[15:0]read_index;//j


    initial begin
      write_index = 16'b0000000000000000;
      read_index = 16'b0100111000100000;
    end


    always@(posedge delay_clk) begin
       read_index = read_index+1;    
       memory [write_index] <= data_in;
       data_out <= memory[read_index];   
    end

endmodule
```

I want to make a 1 second delay by using the circular memory.
I generate bitstream and program it to FGPA but there is no sound come out.
So how can i improve this verilog codes?

Answer (score 0):

You don't increment `write_index` anywhere (like you do with `read_index`), it will cause this hardware to overwrite 1 memory cell over and over again. I don't think this is what you wanted, it beats the idea of using a memory array.

If you intend to store `read_index` in some kind of a memory element use `<=` assignment like the ones for `memory` and `data_out`.

Your `write_index` and `read_index` are a 16 bit variables. You use them to iterate over a 20k cells memory. <s>They will overflow at some point. Is this intentional?</s> I mean why 16bits and is it ok for those indexes to point at e.g. address 41k?

Comment: A 16 bit variable has a range 0-65k+. Why would it overflow with only 20k?

Comment: So should I add write write_index <= write_index+1? 16 bit variable range is up to 65535, how will that overflow?

Comment: I didn't make myself clear, I'm sorry. I was wondering why these values are 16bit and is it ok for them to point at e.g. element 41k since we have only 20k cells. Something for op to consider.